# How to set combobox data from a model in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Generally I set combobox data as follows:
`cbo.addItem("xyz",QVariant(1))` -- xyz is value shown in the cbo and 1 is its data

I am setting checkable cbo value from a pyqt model as follows:

```
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(cases_array), 1)
for index, case in enumerate(cases_array): 
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(case[1])
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
    model.setItem(index, 0, item)
cbo.setModel(model)
```

It works great. But when I do `cbo.itemData(0).toPyObject()` I dont get any value.

How can I set cbo data value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs points out:

> #### void QComboBox::addItem(const QString &text, const QVariant
> &userData = QVariant())
>
> Adds an item to the combobox with the given text, and containing the
> specified userData (stored in the [Qt::UserRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)). The item is appended
> to the list of existing items.

The userData is associated with the [`Qt::UserRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) role so you must use that role (or a larger one).

Considering the above, I have created the following example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    cases_array = [
        ("text1", "data1"),
        ("text2", "data2"),
        ("text3", "data3"),
        ("text4", "data4"),
    ]
    cbo = QtGui.QComboBox()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 1)
    for index, (text, data) in enumerate(cases_array):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        item.setData(data, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        model.appendRow(item)
    cbo.setModel(model)

    def on_current_index_changed(index):
        text = cbo.itemText(index)
        data = cbo.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        check_state = cbo.itemData(index, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        print(index, text, data, check_state)

    cbo.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(on_current_index_changed)
    cbo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```